# Calling REST API from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, architecture, software-design

I have a REST API to push an object to a message queue (Rabbit MQ). My product owner asked me to call that API from a SQL Server stored procedure.

Is it a normal and good way?

Is this the right way? If not, what's the best solution for my problem?

I know SQL Server can call REST API and also I know high level languages 
like C# are better.

and my problem is how can i convincing my product owner to use C# instate of TSQL.

Comment: Define "my problem" please. Also, I have never heard a product owner makes technical decisions. Or are you talking about your product architect?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst the product owner of this project is the technical manager of our compay :-(

Comment: In this case he will have a good explanation for you why his request makes sense. Maybe worth sharing these details with us instead of asking for arguments why C# is better. BTW, C# is a programming language. You cannot call a service from a programming language. What you can do is writing a service, app, bot, or web page that calls a service. ;-)

Comment: our technical manager reason just is "I can do it with sql server easier than C# .net " :|. finally i'll call api from sql server using TSQL :| :| :| :-(

Answer (score 0):

from the security prospect - it is not recommend to call the database directly because the data from the api may have some security issues that need to be handled before running it on the data base. for example, it can has a scripts  that can delete the data on the database if you run it directly on the databse server. you can prevent it if you handle it in separate layer.

from practical reasons - you may want to check the data, change it, normalize it, etc, before you insert it to the database. from outside the database it will be easier to do so. c# has a lot of built in functions that can help you with that.

general good practice - it is good practice to separate the logic layer from the data layer.

better support and easier to maintain - it easier, for example to do debugging from the c# code than from sql code. also, you can catch problems before they ruin the database.

hope it is help you.

Comment: As simple as this: